# Consistency of OLS estimator with unobservable variable

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, estimators, consistency

Suppose I have the next model

$Y_i = \alpha_i + \beta_i X_i + u_i$

where $u_i - N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\alpha_i$ is unobservable, also $E(X_i \alpha_i) \neq 0$

My OLS estimator for $\beta_i$ is

$\hat{\beta_i} = \frac{\sum{Y_i X_i} - \sum{\alpha_i X_i}}{\sum{X_i^2}}$

It is unbiased, but I don't know what I did wrong but it is also ***consistent*** when it's supposed to be ***inconsistent***.

$Plim (\hat{\beta_i}) = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum{\alpha_i X_i}}{\frac{1}{n} \sum{X_i^2}} + \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum{\beta_i} Xi^2}{\frac{1}{n} \sum{X_i^2}} + \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum{u_i} X_i}{\frac{1}{n} \sum{X_i^2}} - \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum{\alpha_i X_i}}{\frac{1}{n} \sum{X_i^2}}$

$Plim (\hat{\beta_i}) = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum{\alpha_i X_i}}{\frac{1}{n} \sum{X_i^2}} + \beta_i + 0 - \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum{\alpha_i X_i}}{\frac{1}{n} \sum{X_i^2}}$

$Plim (\hat{\beta_i}) = \beta_i $

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See, for example, [these answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182109/what-is-the-difference-between-bias-and-inconsistency).

Comment: @runr I don't see how that relates with this, to be honest

Comment: Omitted variable bias (the $\alpha$ parameter you leave out) essentially carries over to the error term $\varepsilon$ (just rewrite $\varepsilon := u_i + \alpha X_i$), making the errors correlated with $X$ ( notice that $\operatorname{Cov}(\varepsilon,X) = 0 + \operatorname{Cov}(\alpha X_i,X_i) \neq 0$) . Then, the arguments from the answer follows

Comment: Highlighting this part from the linked answer: $\hat \beta$ approaches  $\beta + {\rm Cov}(X, \epsilon) / {\rm Var}(X)$ as $n\to\infty$ (which is $\neq$ $\beta$ due to ${\rm Cov}(X, \epsilon) \neq 0$ (omitted variable bias))